# Asp.Net Gridview displaying data in both columns and rows

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am looking to display only 1 data field from the database table grid view in both columns and row wise rather than displaying all of them in rows.

Literally in data sense it looks like the following :

```
    Column1  Column2  Column3
```

Row1    Data1    Data2    Data3

Row2    Data4    Data5    Data6

Row3    Data7    Data8    Data9

To be precise I want to display only the product's image from the database table ignoring the other fields so  i just want the products image to appear in a table.

The actual output should like the image below 
![Products table][1]

http://www.google.com.au/imgres?q=e+shop+in+table&um=1&hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&biw=1280&bih=921&tbm=isch&tbnid=x060V2C4fKhuCM:&imgrefurl=http://mixing-media.com/noticias/index&docid=p-enmrO8qB8a3M&w=499&h=486&ei=4MpeTrHoIunImAX0wqQF&zoom=1&iact=rc&dur=317&page=8&tbnh=136&tbnw=140&start=211&ndsp=31&ved=1t:429,r:21,s:211&tx=46&ty=54

Answer (score 0):

you have to turn `AutoGenerateColumns` off for this, then put the columns inside the gridview yourself.

```
<asp:gridview id="gv1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">
    <columns>
         // insert your columns here
    </columns>
</asp:gridview>
```

in the columns, you can insert databound columns, template columns, etc. template columns are customisable.

[see this for more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752213.aspx)

Comment: I do understand that, sorry if I wasn't clear. Actually I wish to have the data to be displayed in columns and then in the following row of first column.   

Something making it repeat in column and not in row. Unfortunately GridView doesn't have a RepeatLayout or order.